# Parse XML fails with NullPointerException when attribute is xlmns only

Tags: apex, xml, dom, parsing, xmlparsing

I got a sample XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootNode>
    <Sample1 xmlns:key1="yyy">
        <Sample11>ABC</Sample11>
    </Sample1>
    <Sample2 xmlns="zzz">
        <Sample21>ABC</Sample21>
    </Sample2>
</RootNode>
```

Now I try to parse the inside of that XML.

```
String res = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<RootNode>' +
'    <Sample1 xmlns:key1="yyy">' +
'        <Sample11>ABC</Sample11>' +
'    </Sample1>' +
'    <Sample2 xmlns="zzz">' +
'        <Sample21>ABC</Sample21>' +
'    </Sample2>' +
'</RootNode>';

Dom.document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(res);
Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
```

Now for `xmlns:key1=`, getChildElements() runs fine.

```
//Ok, outputs something
Dom.XMLNode sample1 = address.getChildElement('Sample1', '');
System.debug(sample1.getChildElements());
```

However, Now for `xmlns=`, getChildElements() throws NullPointerException.

```
//NullPointerException!
Dom.XMLNode sample2 = address.getChildElement('Sample2', '');
System.debug(sample2.getChildElements());
```

I am thinking that my XML is "somewhat wrong". Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is due to the default namespace ("xmlns") declared for the "Sample2" element in your XML. When a default namespace is declared, all child elements within that scope are considered to be in that namespace unless they have a namespace prefix explicitly defined.

In order to work with elements in a default namespace, you need to specify the namespace URI when using methods like getChildElement() and getChildElements(). You can do this by passing the namespace URI *of those elements* as the second argument of these methods.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to handle the default namespace:

```
String res = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<RootNode>' +
'    <Sample1 xmlns:key1="yyy">' +
'        <Sample11>ABC</Sample11>' +
'    </Sample1>' +
'    <Sample2 xmlns="zzz">' +
'        <Sample21>ABC</Sample21>' +
'    </Sample2>' +
'</RootNode>';

Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(res);
Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();

// For default namespace, get the Sample2 element using
// the namespace URI declared in itself
Dom.XMLNode sample2 = root.getChildElement('Sample2', 'zzz');

// Get the child elements of Sample2
Dom.XMLNode[] sample2ChildElements = sample2.getChildElements();

// Output the child elements
System.debug(sample2ChildElements);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your fixed code, but it still doesn't work :(. However, I found out the solution: replace the namespaceURI in `Dom.XMLNode sample2 = root.getChildElement('Sample2', namespaceURI);` with 'zzz'. I think this is because the Sample2 tag is also "within the scope" of the namespace. Maybe if you edited the answer, I'll accept it

Comment: you can edit the answer directly i think